# Firebase trigger on delete

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Im trying to make a function where I can identify who delete, the problem is Im not getting any answer from the firebase server, someone could help me ? Thanks

```
exports.deleteFunction = functions.database.ref('/clientes')
.onDelete((context) => {
  // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
  console.log("delete");
  console.log(context);
});
```

Here is the function who is deleting

```
confirm = (e) => {
 if (id_deleta) {
      firebaseDatabase.ref('/clientes/categorias/').child(id_deleta)
            .remove();
      notification('success', 'Excluido com sucesso');
      this.callCategoria();
  } else {
    notification('error', 'Ocorreu um erro, tente mais tarde');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Code correction

The `onDelete` event handler is [defined](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_database_.refbuilder#on-delete) as

```
function(non-null functions.database.DataSnapshot, optional non-null functions.EventContext)
```

So in your code above, `.onDelete((context) => {` should be `.onDelete((snapshot, context) => {`.

#### Getting the deleted ID

Next, if you are trying to get the value of `id_deleta` from the `onDelete` event, you can use `var id_deleta = snapshot.key`.

```
exports.deleteFunction = functions.database.ref('/clientes')
.onDelete((snapshot, context) => {
  var id_deleta = snapshot.key;
  console.log("deleted ID %s", id_deleta); // logs "deleted ID 1234", etc.
  console.log(snapshot.val()); // logs the deleted data, no need for this
  console.log(context); // logs the event context
});
```